# df.groupby one column, count values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in this format (with many more rows, hundreds of different values in `col2`):

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': ['black', 'black', 'brown', 'black', 'green', 'red', 'black', 'black'],
     'col2': ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'snake', 'snake', 'bird', 'bird']})
```

I know I can group all the animal entries in `col2` together with

```
grouped = dftest.groupby('col2')
```

I want to use `grouped` df to count the combinations of colors in `col1`, grouped by the values in `col2`.

For example, both the `cat` and `bird` grouping have `black/black` in `col1`, so `black/black = 2`. Only the snake has `red/green`, so `red/green  = 1`. Desired output:

```
black/black = 2
black/brown = 1
green/red = 1
```

Comment: There is no red in your example.

Comment: Oops! Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You group by `'col2'` and use `'/'.join(sorted(x))` to get the possible color combinations. The `'/'.join(sorted(x))` will take all values in a group, and join them together into one string. So if `'black'` and `'white'` are in a group, it will join them together into the string `'black/white'`. Also, I sort the values so it isn't possible to get `'black/white'` in one group, and `'white/black'` in another. This lambda function is applied to each group. Then use `Counter` to store counts in dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(dftest.groupby('col2')['col1'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(x))))
```

Output:

```
{'black/black': 2, 'black/brown': 1, 'green/red': 1}
```

Or alternately, you could use `value_counts` instead of using `Counter`. It will output a series:

```
dftest.groupby('col2')['col1'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(x))).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
black/black    2
green/red      1
black/brown    1
```

Comment: This works, but could you put in a little more information about the `lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(x))` portion? I'd like to have a better breakdown of what's going on so I can apply it elsewhere. :)

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation on `lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(x))`, hope that makes sense.